# After xml mapping fields in Excel are coming blank

Tags: xml, excel

in the attached screenshot we can see after `xml` maps drag and dropped into the Excel fields. Excel fields are coming as blank

[image: 1]

Comment: no attached screenshot :( As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think if you migrate your question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) you will take better answers there, But if you have any problem on programming we can help you in SO ;).